# How do I query SELECT name FROM movies WHERE category LIKE :search - with adding some string before and after SEARCH

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I have query:

```
SELECT name FROM movies WHERE category LIKE :search
```

I have multiple ids in column category : 1,81,23
To better search want to add comma at the beginning and end of :search in query to be like ',1,81,23,' for search specific id in pattern ',XX,'

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT name FROM movies WHERE category LIKE :search');
$stmt->bindValue(':search', "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Need to find single id

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.name
FROM(
      SELECT 'searchString' AS Keyword
      FROM movies
    ) AS a 
INNER JOIN movies AS b
ON a.Keyword like '%'+b.category+'%'
```

Put your user input to 'searchString', it would be work. When you input ',1,18,23,', it would show three records.